# The "transform" parameter of tube in Asymptote

Tags: 3d, asymptote

From the doc of **tube**:

> surface tube(path3 g, coloredpath section,
>                transform T(real)=new transform(real t) {return identity();},
>                real corner=1, real relstep=0);
>
> draws a tube along g with cross section section, after applying the transformation T(t) at
>   relpoint(g,t).

However, when I run this code:

```
import tube;
import graph3;
size(5cm,0);
currentprojection = orthographic(4,4,14); 

triple f(real x){
  return (x, x*x, 0);
}

path3 p = graph(f, -1, 1, operator ..);

transform T(real t){
    return scale(t*(1-t)/500);
}

draw(tube(p, unitcircle, T), purple);

draw(shift(relpoint(p,0))*scale3(0.1)*unitsphere, black);
draw(shift(relpoint(p,1))*scale3(0.1)*unitsphere, green);
```

I get:

[image]

That sounds strange to me. Since `T(0) = T(1) = scale(0)`, I expected a 0 diameter at both endpoints of the path, but this is not what I get at `relpoint(p,1)` (the green point).

It seems that I get the expected result when I do:

```
transform T(real t){
    return scale(t*(25-t)/500);
}
```

[image]

That would mean that `t` runs from 0 to 25 in `T`.

Does `t` really runs from 0 to 25? Why 25? What am I misunderstanding?

I'm using Asymptote version 2.44.

Comment: Looks like the magic number is n/4 where n is the number of points of the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single cubic Bézier segment is parameterized from 0 to 1 and has 4 control points. Your path is generated by sampling f at ngraph=100 (in graph_settings.asy) points, which generates a path3 of length 25, parameterized from 0 to 25.

Comment: Thanks John for explanation. But with the documentation we can expect a `relative point` behavior ?

Comment: I think the document should be updated. I suggest OP wrire an issue in Asymptote' github site.